# Logical Venn Diagrams

Tags: math, logic, venn-diagram

I have this question :

[image]

Unfortunately, my book didn't provide definition and how to draw/read a logic venn diagram, i have to look at the internet but couldn't find any understandable explanation

From what i understand, the logics for the three diagrams are :

> 1. X AND NOT (Y OR Z)
> 2. NOT X AND (Y OR Z)
> 3. Y AND NOT (X OR Z)

Am i right ? Please correct me if i'm wrong

By the ways, does the question mean to combine all three diagrams with OR operation, like :

> 1 OR 2 OR 3

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Comment: This is a maths question, not a programming question. Ask on [maths.se]

Comment: I did not get the question properly. What are the last four options?

Comment: I guess the figure has nothing to do with the options as they don't match! Please refer to a suitable book OR please re-phrase your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not understand the question correctly. Here's the logic for the three Venn Diagrams:

**1.** Your logic for the first Venn Diagram is correct: `X AND NOT (Y OR Z)`

**2.** Your logic for the second Venn Diagram is slightly incorrect, if you look at the Venn Diagram: It is simply `NOT (X)` (Everything except `X`).

**3.** In this case as well, the logic is simply `Y`.

Now if we perform `OR` operation on these three:

```
  (X AND NOT (Y OR Z)) + NOT(X) + Y 
=  X AND NOT(Y) AND NOT(Z) OR NOT(X) OR Y             [By de Morgan's law]
```

which matches option **c**.

**NOTE:** Your second and third logics would have been correct if `X, Y` and `Z` were the only three regions in the diagram. However there is also a region outside all of them - bounded by the box. You might want to look up on the internet about basics of Venn Diagram, it's one of the easiest things to learn IMO!

Comment: very clear, now i understand the Venn Diagram better also, thanks alot, mate